# Nested form not inserting into DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have a nested form which is refusing to insert a new record into the DB, despite the parent inserting fine. Undoubtedly an obvious one, but can someone advise why?

Parent model:

```
class Delivery < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :orders_attributes
  has_many :orders, as: :orderable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :orders
```

Nested model

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :info
  belongs_to :orderable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :delivery
```

Parent controller

```
  def new
    @delivery = Delivery.new
    order = @delivery.orders.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @delivery }
    end
  end
```

Form

```
= form_for @delivery do |f|

  = fields_for :orders do |builder|
    = builder.label :info
    = builder.text_area :info
  .actions
    = f.submit
```

Output:

> Started POST "/deliveries" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-13 16:06:53 +0100
>   Processing by DeliveriesController#create as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"MdNjphnBQaaHdxelT7RnWDNG2XPpDTQipDKAOkT57h0=",
>   "orders"=>{"info"=>"1222"}, "commit"=>"Create Delivery"}    (0.1ms) 
>   begin transaction   SQL (2.7ms)  INSERT INTO "deliveries"
>   ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 13
>   Feb 2013 15:06:53 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Wed, 13 Feb 2013
>   15:06:53 UTC +00:00]]    (1.3ms)  commit transaction Redirected to

You can see it's posting the order data, but it's not putting it into the DB correctly... What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you need

```
form_for @delivery do |f|

  = f.fields_for :orders do |builder|
    = builder.label :info
    = builder.text_area :info
  .actions
    = f.submit
```

notice the f.fields_for is different

Comment: you are welcome - I see you are fairly new here so may not know that you should accept whatever you think is the correct answer.  This helps others who are googling, and enhances the answers reputation.

Comment: Done - it wouldn't let me do it for 10 minutes for some reason but it has worked now!

Comment: Made the same mistake.  Good catch!